# ipad: keybord at wrong position

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios5, keyboard

When I have switched to another view (After returning from taking a picture or after switching to a view to select stuff in table) the ipad keyboard appears at the wrong position.
When I select a text field, I see this on my Ipad and on the simulator. (can't post images yet). If I turn my ipad (so that it aligns horizontal) and rotate back the keyboard is back normal.

https://devforums.apple.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-701040-19966/Screen+Shot+2012-07-20+at+16.36.20.png

My code to switch to the camera for taking a picture...

```
- (IBAction)getCameraPicture:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.title = @"CameraPicture";
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

My code to switch to a view with a table in it :

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewControllerSpanoTechProducts animated:YES];
```

code for returning after selecting stuff :

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

how my app works: you have a main screen with buttons and textfield to fill in a form. when you push a button to select a product I switch to another viewcontroller with a table where you can select a product and a button 'done'. If you click the 'done' button I switch back to the original view.. hope this helps?
I'm just started with iOS.. Any help is appriciated!

Comment: Flow of your application is not clear, can you give more detail...??

Comment: I have edited my post. hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

At the time of switch user this code:

```
[yourTextFieldObject resignFirstResponder];
```

This might work.

Comment: thanx for reply, bu it doesnt work. Think it worked in one order of actions, but i have have multiple text fields and viewcontrollers.. other thoughts?